# How do I query an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb-query

I have been trying multiple queries but still can't figure it out. I have multiple documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b51f519a33e7f54161a0efb"),
    "assigneesEmail" : [ 
        "felipe@gmail.com"
    ],
    "organizationId" : "5b4e0de37accb41f3ac33c00",
    "organizationName" : "PaidUp Volleyball Club",
    "type" : "athlete",
    "firstName" : "Mylo",
    "lastName" : "Fernandes",
    "description" : "",
    "status" : "active",
    "createOn" : ISODate("2018-07-20T14:43:37.610Z"),
    "updateOn" : ISODate("2018-07-20T14:43:37.610Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need help writing a query where I can find this document by looking up the email in any part of the array element *assigneeEmail*. Any suggestions? I have tried $elemMatch but still could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my query was just incorrect. I figured it out.